# Side effects of same context-root with different path

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, weblogic, web-deployment

I have an application which has a context-root as below,

```
<module id="test1">
  <web>
    <web-uri>test1.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>main</context-root>
  </web>
</module>
```

Now I have created a new war for a functionality, but still I wanted to start with same context-root as "main". Why because there are some layers of security is applied when someone hit with "/main".

So I made as below and it works,

```
<module id="test1">
   <web>
    <web-uri>test1.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>main</context-root>
   </web>
</module>
<module id="test2">
   <web>
    <web-uri>test2.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>main/test2</context-root>
   </web>
</module>
```

I wanted to know is there any side effects as I have configured same context root with just different path and is it allowed ?